# MooTools if/then/else toggling based on presence of a css class

Tags: javascript, css, class, mootools, toggle

I'm trying to toggle a class and perform several other actions based on the css class assigned to a particular div.

I'm using MooTools 1.2.5.

The div looks like this:

```
<div class="loginbox"> Login Form Here </div>
```

I have a link on the page that looks like this:

```
<a href="#" class="loginlink">Show/Hide Login</a>
```

For visitors with Javascript enabled the form is automatically hidden by my script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.addEvent('domready',function() {

    $$('div.loginbox').addClass('hidden');

    $$('a.loginlink').each(function(linkitem){

        linkitem.addEvent('click', function(i){

            displayis = $$('div.loginbox').hasClass('hidden');

            if (displayis) {
                $$('div.loginbox').removeClass('hidden');
                // do several things
            } else {
                $$('div.loginbox').addClass('hidden');
                // do several other things          
            };

        });
    }); 

}); 

</script>
```

The first time the "Show/Hide Login" link is clicked everything appears to work fine and the div with the class "loginbox" appears on the screen.

The second time "Show/Hide Login" link is clicked nothing happens.  Using console.log to try to figure out what is going on it looks like the first part of the if statement is being evaluated as true when its clearly false.

A curious thing about the above script is if I change the "loginbox" to a id and adjust the script accordingly it works fine. I'm using a CMS which requires the "loginbox" be a class, not a div.

Simply using ".toggleClass('hidden')" also works great except I want to do more than just toggle the class.

Thanks for your time.

-Brent

Answer (score 3):

`displayis = $$('div.loginbox').hasClass('hidden');` -> this is pretty redundant as it does hasClass to all members of the html collection, pushing the results into an array.

rewrite to:

```
var theHiddenEl = document.getElement("div.loginbox.hidden");
```

it will return an element if it has both classes.

```
if (theHiddenEl) {
    theHiddenEl.toggleClass("hidden"); // or removeClass etc. 
    // ... more stuff
}
...
```

Comment: I solved my problem by changing 'if (displayis) {'  to 'if (displayis=="true") {'. I'm not really sure why that works.

Comment: When I tested this getElement("div.loginbox, div.hidden") always finds div.loginbox but it doesn't tell me if div.hidden is is applied or not.  I need to know in order to determine which part of the if/else statement should execute.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gbP9F/ - check this. sorry, i had messed up the selector. works fine now and this fiddle will also show you why your way is wrong in that it will return an array of false's with perhaps 1 true.

Comment: applying a method to a collection does a .each iteration which then pushes the result into an array. essentially, you are saying `if ([false, false, true, false, false, false] == true)` which is wrong, whichever way you look at it.